# Docker - Can´t change default password of phpmyadmin

Tags: docker

In docker compose file i have phpmyadmin, like this

```
 phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        hostname: 'phpmyadmin'
        container_name: 'phpmyadmin'
        links:
          - database:db
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        ports:
          - 8000:80
```

When i use this password and user to try login in phpmyadmin, returns that no authorized. So, how can i change default user and password for phpmyadmin docker?

Comment: Are you sure these are not the env variables for the db service? Looking at the hub, the variables for phpmyadmin all start with `PMA_`.

Answer (score 6):

From https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/

> phpMyAdmin connects using your MySQL server credentials. Please check your corresponding database server image for information on the default username and password or how to specify your own custom credentials during installation.

The MySQL server credentials can be defined in MySQL docker container by using the MYSQL_* environment variables. Here is a docker-compose example from the dockerhub website:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: notSecureChangeMe

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
```

Here you can login in phpmyadmin as root with the password "notSecureChangeMe" (Server: db).

If you want to login in phpmyadmin directly without providing user and password then you need to use config authentication mode (https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/release_5_0_4/setup.html#config-authentication-mode) and provide the credentials in phpmyadmin config file.

This is very easy to configure in docker-compose file (by using PMA_* environment variables):

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: notSecureChangeMe

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: 'db'
      PMA_USER: 'root'
      PMA_PASSWORD: 'notSecureChangeMe'
```